# Receiving Promise {<pending>} back from .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have an API call in `api.js`:

```js
 export const getGraphData = (domain, userId, testId) => {
   return axios({
     url: `${domain}/api/${c.embedConfig.apiVersion}/member/${userId}/utests/${testId}`,
     method: 'get',
   });
 };
```

I have a React helper that takes that data and transforms it.

```js
import { getGraphData } from './api';

const dataObj = (domain, userId, testId) => {

  const steps = getGraphData(domain, userId, testId)
  .then((result) => {
    return result.attributes;
  });

  console.log(steps);

  // const steps = test.get('steps');
  const expr = /select/;

  // build array of steps that we have results in
  const resultsSteps = [];

  steps.forEach((step) => {
    // check for types that contain 'select', and add them to array
    if (expr.test(step.get('type'))) {
      resultsSteps.push(step);
    }
  });

  const newResultsSteps = [];

  resultsSteps.forEach((item, i) => {
    const newMapStep = new Map();
    const itemDescription = item.get('description');
    const itemId = item.get('id');
    const itemOptions = item.get('options');
    const itemAnswers = item.get('userAnswers');
    const newOptArray = [];
    itemOptions.forEach((element) => {
      const optionsMap = new Map();
      let elemName = element.get('value');
      if (!element.get('value')) { elemName = element.get('caption'); }
      const elemPosition = element.get('position');
      const elemCount = element.get('count');

      optionsMap.name = elemName;
      optionsMap.position = elemPosition;
      optionsMap.value = elemCount;
      newOptArray.push(optionsMap);
    });
    newMapStep.chartType = 'horizontalBar';
    newMapStep.description = itemDescription;
    newMapStep.featured = 'false';
    newMapStep.detailUrl = '';
    newMapStep.featuredStepIndex = i + 1;
    newMapStep.id = itemId;
    newMapStep.isValid = 'false';
    newMapStep.type = 'results';
    const listForNewOptArray = List(newOptArray);
    newMapStep.data = listForNewOptArray;
    newMapStep.userAnswers = itemAnswers;
    newResultsSteps.push(newMapStep);
  });

  return newResultsSteps;
};

export default dataObj;
```

The issue is `steps`, when logged outside the `.then()` returns a `Promise {<pending>}`. If I log `results.attributes` inside the `.then()`, I see the data fully returned.

Comment: Your mixing sync and async code - you cant read `steps` below the chain of `getGraphData` and expect it to magically have resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wait until your async call is resolved. You can do this by chaining on another `then`:

```
getGraphData(domain, userId, testId)
  .then((result) => {
    return result.attributes;
  })
  .then(steps => {
     // put the rest of your method here
  });
```

You can also look at [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if your platform supports it which would allow code closer to your original

```
const steps = await getGraphData(domain, userId, testId)
  .then((result) => {
    return result.attributes;
  });

// can use steps here
```

Comment: Actually i think `result.attributes` is not a promise in this case this is just the expected result, you're calling a `.then()` in excess.

Comment: @Dyo no, thats not the way it works. You can return another promise or a value from `then` but either way it resolves to another promise.  In the case you return a value it is wrapped in `Promise.resolve(youReturnValue)`.

Comment: With the second `.then()` block, if I do any processing on `steps` inside it, I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: steps.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @Jamiec I think you're confusing the `response.json().then()` you do with `fetch` library, `axios` can display the result data in one promise.

Comment: @TWLATL if you `console.log(steps)` in the second `then` what do you get?

Comment: @jamiec If I `console.log(steps)` inside the second `.then()`, I get the data returned. However, if I try to move the processing in to that 2nd then block, I get an error mentioned above. 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: steps.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @TWLATL when you say "get the data returned" is it an actual javascript array? Or is it perhaps a string of json?

Comment: @Jamiec it is the actual javascript array.

Comment: @TWLATL if it was then `forEach` would work. That error message implies it is *not* an array. Try `JSON.parse(steps).forEach( i => console.log(i))` to confirm.

Comment: @Dyo Im really not mistaking anything. Re-read my first response to you, and try it out.

Comment: @TWLATL I cant see that - the link goes to my dropbox and says folder screenshot is not available. If you want to share a screenshot maybe use imgur or something

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, `.then()` works with returned value, but i don't get what's the point of doing so, this useless `.then()` just complicates the answer.

Comment: @Dyo It was part of the *question*. I guess to the OP it just transforms the json response to the actual bit they wanted. I would personally do it all in 1 `then`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to transform your fetched data :

**1st option : create a async function that returns a promise with the modified data :**

```
const dataObj = (domain, userId, testId) => {
  return getGraphData(domain, userId, testId).then((result) => {
    const steps = result.attributes;
    const expr = /select/;
    // build array of steps that we have results in
    const resultsSteps = [];

    steps.forEach((step) => {
      // check for types that contain 'select', and add them to array
      if (expr.test(step.get('type'))) {
        resultsSteps.push(step);
      }
    });

    const newResultsSteps = [];

    resultsSteps.forEach((item, i) => {
      const newMapStep = new Map();
      const itemDescription = item.get('description');
      const itemId = item.get('id');
      const itemOptions = item.get('options');
      const itemAnswers = item.get('userAnswers');
      const newOptArray = [];
      itemOptions.forEach((element) => {
        const optionsMap = new Map();
        let elemName = element.get('value');
        if (!element.get('value')) {
          elemName = element.get('caption');
        }
        const elemPosition = element.get('position');
        const elemCount = element.get('count');

        optionsMap.name = elemName;
        optionsMap.position = elemPosition;
        optionsMap.value = elemCount;
        newOptArray.push(optionsMap);
      });
      newMapStep.chartType = 'horizontalBar';
      newMapStep.description = itemDescription;
      newMapStep.featured = 'false';
      newMapStep.detailUrl = '';
      newMapStep.featuredStepIndex = i + 1;
      newMapStep.id = itemId;
      newMapStep.isValid = 'false';
      newMapStep.type = 'results';
      const listForNewOptArray = List(newOptArray);
      newMapStep.data = listForNewOptArray;
      newMapStep.userAnswers = itemAnswers;
      newResultsSteps.push(newMapStep);
    });
    return newResultsSteps;
  });
};
```

With es7 async/await syntax it should be :

```
const dataObj = async (domain, userId, testId) => {
    const result = await getGraphData(domain, userId, testId);
    const steps = result.attributes;
    ... modify the data
}
```

Then keep in mind that this function returns a promise, you'll need to wait for it to get the result, example in a react component :

```
componentDidMount(){
   dataObj('mydomain', 'myuserId', 'mytestId').then((res) => {
       this.setState({ data: res });
   }
}
```

The component will update when the promise is resolve, you can then use the data (you'll need to handle the undefined data state in render method)

**2nd option : Create a sync function to modify the data :**

```
const dataObj = (steps) => {
    const expr = /select/;
    const resultsSteps = [];

    steps.forEach((step) => {
    ...
    }
    return newResultsSteps;
};
```

To have the same result as option 1 in our component we'll use it like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
   getGraphData('mydomain', 'myuserId', 'mytestId').then((res) => {
       const modifiedData = dataObj(res);
       this.setState({ data: modifiedData });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how promises work. The data is not ready when you are trying to use it so you should move all your processing into the `.then`. The reason your variable is a `Promise {<pending>}` is because you can chain other things onto it.

Something like:

```
steps.then((steps) => {
    ...
});
```