# Promise {<Pending>} Error When Retrieving Values using REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I am new to React, and I hope to learn a lot from this community.

I have a BoredAPI.js file that gets values from "Kanye Rest API", and I am setting the passed value into the `setValues` useState in App.js. In addition to that, I am using the `async/await` properties shown in existing posts such as this - [Receiving Promise {<pending>} back from .then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767712/receiving-promise-pending-back-from-then). However, I continue to have an error `Promise {<Pending>}` in the console log `console.log("App Statement: ", BoredAPI());`.

Could someone provide me insights on what I am doing wrong? I really appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you.

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BoredAPI from "./BoredAPI";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues(BoredAPI());
    console.log("App Statement: ", BoredAPI());
  });

  return <html>{values}</html>;
}
```

**BoredAPI.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BoredAPI = async () => {
  const config = { auth: { username: "", password: "" } };
  const boredAPI = await axios
    .get("https://api.kanye.rest/", {
      // headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Kanye Rest: ", response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
  return boredAPI;
};

export default BoredAPI;
```

Comment: Invert the `setValues` to `BoredAPI().then(v => setValues(v))`

Comment: `BoredAPI` is an async function, so you need to await it when calling it. i.e. `await BoredAPI()`

Comment: In most situations where you are grabbing data from an external source using a network requests you'll be dealing with promises.  They're a way of preventing the network request from blocking the other execution of your code by making them asynchronous.  Check out the MDN article on promises for more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @ChrisSandvik Thank you for this article! I wish to upvote your comment, but unfortunately, I need 14 more reputations in order to do so. :(

Comment: @May no worries, I'm just here to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoredAPI` is an asynchronous function. As such, you always have to call it from within an asynchronous context.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    BoredAPI().then(result => {
        setValues(result);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await BoredAPI();
        setValues(result);
        console.log(result);
    })();
});
```

The second example is known as an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).